# What does OperationCycle mean in DTC status byte?

Tags: operation, diagnostics, msdtc, autosar, uds

[enter image desscription here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yurAY.png)
I don't understand what is OperationCycle in DTC status byte.
Could you please explain it?

OperationCycle in DTC status byte means

Answer (score 1):

According to Autosar [dem spec](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/classic/19-11/AUTOSAR_SWS_DiagnosticEventManager.pdf) , An ‘operation cycle’ is the base of the event qualifying and also Dem scheduling (e.g. ignition key off-on cycles, driving cycles, etc.).

Typically, One operation cycle starts at ign on and ends with ign off, power-on and power-off, or enter sleep mode and exit sleep mode.

Actually, an operation cycle starts when `Dem_SetOperationCycleState(operationcycle_id, DEM_CYCLE_STATE_START)` is called and ends when `Dem_SetOperationCycleState(operationcycle_id, DEM_CYCLE_STATE_END)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

The operation cycle (also known as 'drive cycle') is a combination of states that the vehicle's ECUs need to pass before an emission test can be carried out.

Next to starting and stopping the engine it involves several driving conditions (open loop, closed loop), but also non-driving conditions, such as AC.

For more information you can search for NEFZ or WLTP, which are both drive cycle standardizations.